# The application event not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events, aura-handler

I know what I am asking is a very basic example question. But I am trying to understand the application event using an example and it is not working. I tried to figure it out all by myself for a long time, but couldn't succeed. Can anyone kindly let me know what am I doing wrong. The code is as below

> appEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template">
</aura:event>
```

> appEventChild.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name='four' type='c:appEvent' />
    <lightning:button label='Submit' onclick='{!c.show}' />
</aura:component>
```

> appEventChildController.js

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get('e.c:appEvent');
        //console.log(evt);
        console.log('child called');
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

> appEventParent.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name='four' event='c:appEvent' action='{!c.show}' />
    <c:appEventChild />
</aura:component>
```

> appEventParentController.js

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('parent is invoked');
    }
})
```

> appEventApp.app

```
<aura:application extends='force:slds'>
    <c:appEventParent />
</aura:application>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the `name` attribute on the handlers for an application event. Refer to the [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/253296/54851).

Comment: That Worked! Thank you. If you can add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Because your problem was exactly the same as in the linked question/answer, thus I won't add a new answer here. I have flagged this as duplicate, so once this gets reviewed by the moderators/gets sufficient votes, this will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Ok I Understand. Thank you.